# Handling incorrect parameter value

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have the following function (C++):

```
string dataInYear(int year) {
  if (year < 2000) {
     //don't support retrieving data from before 2000
  }
  //return data for the year >= 2000
}
```

Should I be throwing an exception here if the year < 2000? What about using an output error string as a paramater:

```
string dataInYear(int year, string &error) {
  if (year < 2000) {
     error = "don't support retrieving data from before 2000";
     return "";
  }
  //return data for the year >= 2000
}
```

The reason I'm not sure about using exceptions is that the caller doesn't know just from looking at the header file that this function can throw an exception (rather than just return an empty string). With the second option the caller is forced to acknowledge the method can fail by passing in an error string and checking it after.

Or as a third option:

```
template <class A> struct Failable
{
  bool error;
  A value;
  wxString errorString;
  Failable(wxString errorStr) :  error(true), errorString(errorStr) {}
  Failable(A val) : error(false), value(val) {}
  operator A() const { return value; }
};

Failable<string> dataInYear(int year) {
      if (year < 2000) {
         error = "don't support retrieving data from before 2000";
         return "";
      }
      //return data for the year >= 2000
}

//caller

Failable<string> d = dataInYear(y);
if (d.error) {
  //deal with error
} else {
  string data = d.value;
}
```

Comment: Avoid std::string pointers (most and your usage are wrong). Use a reference instead.

Comment: boost::optional would be a good return value (likely available in C++17)

Comment: One solution is to document `dataInYear` with *Calling this function is UB unless year < 2000*. Look up "design by contract" for more details. There are a million other solutions with practically no way to find the One Correct Solution, so this question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @DieterLücking why should string pointers be avoided (it seems like you are talking about string pointers specifically)

Comment: @nwp, if there are clear problems with a solution that is not opinion, and I don't know that before I've asked the question...

Comment: @Jonathan. the question had an edit (regarding the string pointer)

Comment: It is a good question, but to answer it properly one would need to enumerate all the ways to do error handling, compare advantages and disadvantages and then conclude with "it depends". It is a good topic for a book, but not for SO. I don't blame you for not knowing that, I'm just saying it is a design decision question which attracts opinionated answers and SO cannot handle that besides closing the question.

Comment: Since you are reluctant to use exception specifications (with reason) that rules out the obvious need for the caller to use a try-catch block. In that case a string reference parameter makes it clear the caller would need to check it the result himself.
Alternately, you could handle the exception yourself and pop a message box, return empty string, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I'm not sure about using exceptions is that the **caller doesn't know** just from looking at the header file that this **function can throw an exception**

Well, it's **possible**, using the `throw` keyword:

```
// Header.h
string dataInYear(int year) throw(std::exception);
```

However, if you feel that [exception specifications are bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/114338/24410), then you may just comment that part out. Which at least informs user that this fuction 'can' `throw`.
Alternatively, go for returning an empty string as you have already pointed in your post.

```
auto result = dataInYear(year);
if(result.empty())
  // ... error
```

---

Suppose none of them you like, then have a simple structure, which contains error code within it.

```
template<typename Data>
struct Result
{
  Data data;  // any type can be used besides string
  string error;
};

Result<string> dataInYear(int year)
{
  if(year < 2000)
    return Result<string>{"", "don't support retrieving data from before 2000"};

  return Result<string>{data};
}

...

auto result = dataInYear(year);
if(not result.error.empty())  // if `error` is filled => problem
  // ... error
```

Comment: Everything I've heard about exception specifications is bad, so i figured I shouldn't do this.

Comment: I'd go with an `assert(year < 2000)` over just returning an empty string, helps with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to use an exception specification could be something like this:

```
#include <string>

class APIExample 
{
   std::string m_sErrorMessage;

public:
   APIExample() : m_sErrorMessage("")
   {}

   enum class ReturnCode {
      Ok,
      Error, // Possible to add more codes if you'd like
   };

   ReturnCode dataInYear(int nYear, std::string & sData)
   {
      if (nYear < 2000) {
         m_sErrorMessage = "Year is < 2000";
         return ReturnCode::Error;
      }
      return ReturnCode::Ok;
   }

   ReturnCode getErrorMessage(std::string & sErrorMessage)
   {
      sErrorMessage = m_sErrorMessage;

      return ReturnCode::Ok;
   }
};

int main()
{

   APIExample example;
   std::string sData;
   if (example.dataInYear(1000, sData) != APIExample::ReturnCode::Ok) {
      std::string sError;
      example.getErrorMessage(sError);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that the `enum class ReturnCode` can be extended with additional error / warning codes.

Comment: Aren't exceptions one of the beauties of C++?

Comment: Isn't `ReturnCode` a bit redundant? The caller could just check if the `sErrorMessage`is empty. As is `m_sErrorMessage`: just write directly to a string reference parameter, which the caller can check.

Comment: @Chiel Yeah but I thought he was looking for an alternative to an exception specification/API.

Comment: @KABOOOM `ReturnCode` could be extended with additional enums and error codes. The client might want to throw an exception on some errors, and not on some others, without the enum the client would need to parse the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I'm not sure about using exceptions is that the caller doesn't know just from looking at the header file that this function can throw an exception (rather than just return an empty string).

They *should*! Where are your documenting comments? Those should state that an exception may be thrown when preconditions are violated. And, whether you use exceptions or not, **the preconditions themselves should be listed in said documenting comments anyway**, so the question becomes moot: an error parameter is no better or worse than exceptions, *in that regard*.

Meanwhile, all the other benefits of exceptions come to bear (which I shan't enumerate here).

Comment: Ok, yes it is documented, but should the user not read this, the compiler won't warn the user. (I'm coming from Swift/Java where its explicit to the compiler and user that the method throws an exception.)

Comment: @Jonathan.: Then the user is negligent.